# host mirroring on multiple VM (unique VNETid/uuid)

Tags: tcpdump, mirroring

We want to mirror all traffic going in/out port vnet0, and we want to send it to bridge port vnet2 (where we have a traffic monitoring application) and make sure traffic from vnet2 is excluded on tcpdump running on vnet2

I am using bond0 mirroring to mirror traffic from all the VM present to new VM(vnet2) "tc filter add dev bond0 parent ffff: protocol all u32 match u8 0 0 action mirred egress mirror dev vnet2

tcpdump trace collected at vnet2 should have traces from all the VM except traces from vnet2

Answer (score 0):

get the IP of new VM by below command: 
-> ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'

-> sudo tcpdump -w test.pcap not host